# Flink StreamingFileSink on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to connect the StreamingFileSink to Azure Blob Storage. There is currently no mention of Azure in the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html), but I hoped it will work with the file system abstraction.

After analysing the error, I assume this feature is out of scope right now for Azure Blob Storage.

Now I'd like to be sure that I did not make any mistake and would appreciate any pointers if there is a way to make it work.

**So far i found out:**

This is the exception I see:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/fs/azure/common/hadoop/HadoopRecoverableWriter                                                            
    at org.apache.flink.fs.azure.common.hadoop.HadoopFileSystem.createRecoverableWriter(HadoopFileSystem.java:202)                                         
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.PluginFileSystemFactory$ClassLoaderFixingFileSystem.createRecoverableWriter(PluginFileSystemFactory.java:129)              
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.createRecoverableWriter(SafetyNetWrapperFileSystem.java:69)                                     
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.<init>(Buckets.java:117)                                                           
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink$RowFormatBuilder.createBuckets(StreamingFileSink.java:288)               
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink.initializeState(StreamingFileSink.java:402)                              
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.tryRestoreFunction(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:178)                                
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.functions.StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(StreamingFunctionUtils.java:160)                              
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:96)                               
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator.initializeState(AbstractStreamOperator.java:284)                                    
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.initializeStateAndOpen(StreamTask.java:1006)                                                    
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$beforeInvoke$0(StreamTask.java:454)                                                      
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.beforeInvoke(StreamTask.java:449)                                                               
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:461)                                                                     
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:707)                                                                                      
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:532)                                                                                        
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Now the HadoopRecoverableWriter class method seems to be missing

But in the [flink-azure-fs-hadoop](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-filesystems/flink-azure-fs-hadoop/pom.xml) repository I can find this in the pom.xml

```
<!-- shade Flink's Hadoop FS adapter classes  -->
<relocation>
    <pattern>org.apache.flink.runtime.fs.hdfs</pattern>
    <shadedPattern>org.apache.flink.fs.azure.common.hadoop</shadedPattern>
</relocation>
```

And the shaded package includes this class [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/c96cd9cc01bbd91771cfa571a14858c288d2fe84/flink-filesystems/flink-hadoop-fs/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/fs/hdfs/HadoopFileSystem.java#L202).

Now I had a look at the contents of the flink-azure-fs-hadoop-1.10.0.jar and the shaded package and the RecoverableWriter is missing:

```
HadoopBlockLocation.class
HadoopDataInputStream.class
HadoopDataOutputStream.class
HadoopFileStatus.class
HadoopFileSystem.class
HadoopFsFactory.class
HadoopFsRecoverable.class
```

More digging shows there is actually a filter in the pom.xml shade part which excludes the RecoverableWriter.

```
<filter>
    <artifact>org.apache.flink:flink-hadoop-fs</artifact>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>org/apache/flink/runtime/util/HadoopUtils</exclude>
        <exclude>org/apache/flink/runtime/fs/hdfs/HadoopRecoverable*</exclude>
    </excludes>
</filter>
```

Comment: Note: a ticket in Flink has been filed for this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-17444